# Voice calls in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, voip

There's a server for an app written in Django. There's a need to add Voice Calls feature to the app. The calls will be only between app users initially and over the internet, so I would guess there is no need for a service like Twillio.

How to do it? Is there an example of such a Django app? Should I combine the Django server with a Twisted server?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it myself, but [here is a simple example](http://sharewebegin.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/real-time-voice-chat-example-in-python.html) of a voice chat implemented in python using the pyaudio module.

Regarding your comment about Twisted, I believe you'll have to combine Django with an asynchronous web framework (Twisted, Tornado, etc...) in order to make the voice chat portion of your solution work as expected.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a socket service like pubnub and build your chat app on the front end?
This like might be of use to you. http://webrtc.co/